# Accessing request headers in a Squid redirector

Tags: linux, http, squid, http-headers

I have a redirector enabled in my Squid config file as follows:

```
url_rewrite_program /etc/squid/redirector.php
```

I need to access the original HTTP request headers from within the redirector. I'm not interested in making any changes to the request headers; I only need to be able to read them.

As far as I can tell, Squid only passes the URL to the redirector, but not the request headers. So how can I access these request headers in my redirector?

Update 1: A related side question, is it possible to access POST data within a Squid redirector? I imagine that if this is possible, the mechanism for doing so would be the same as accessing the headers.

Update 2: I believe this is possible using ICAP. I'm looking for a solution that does not involve ICAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** it isn't possible.

**Long answer:** it isn't possible; make use of an ICAP server instead which allows modification of request headers as per the [Squid FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation).